# Use same field name for serializing and unserializing different fields in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have the following models...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Gift(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    message = models.CharField()
```

...the following serializer...

```
class GiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = ('product', 'message', )
```

... and the following class based view associated to '/gifts/'.

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateListAPIView 

class GiftList(CreateListAPIView):
    queryset = Gift.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GiftSerializer
```

**How can I achieve creating gifts with a key 'product' that represent the foreign key primary key like this**

```
self.client.post('/gifts/', {'product': 1, 'message': 'bar'})
```

**but at the same time returning information with the nested product details also with the key 'product'**

```
self.client.get('/gifts/')
# {0: {"product": {"name": "foo"}, "message": "bar"}}
```

---

I somewhat achieved what I want by adding another write-only IntegerField to `GiftSerializer` named `product_pk` and overwriting `to_internal_values`:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    data['product_pk'] = data.pop('product')[0]
    return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

But the problem is, if the validation fails, the exception is returned using the field `product_pk` instead of `product` as I would like it to be.

```
{'product_pk': ['A valid integer is required.']}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it would be to create two serializers,

```
class GiftReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = ('product', 'message', )

class GiftWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = ('product', 'message', )
```

Then in your class based view, you can leverage the `get_serializer_class` hook:

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateListAPIView 

class GiftList(CreateListAPIView):
    queryset = Gift.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GiftSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == ('POST' or 'PUT' or 'PATCH'):
            return GiftWriteSerializer
        else:
            return GiftReadSerializer
```

Comment: It´s a simple solution, but the returned data for a POST would be the pk and not the serialized product

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Just out of curiosity, why do you need to return the product object on the POST request? Presumably, if you have the id of the product then you have made a GET request to /products/ (or whatever), and you would have the product object already in the front end...

Comment: This is the default DRF behaviour actually. By using the same key to return the whole product info, it minimizes the HTTP requests needed to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this work by overriding `to_internal_value` and dynamically modifying fields.

```
product_field = ProductSerializer()
pk_product_field = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
     queryset=Product.objects.all())

class GiftSerializer(object):
    product = product_field

    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = ('product', 'message', )

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        self.fields['product'] = pk_product_field
        internal_value = super().to_internal_value(data)
        self.fields['product'] = product_field
        return internal_value
```